# Getting error while using RestartApp in flutter

Tags: flutter, application-restart

Basically i want to clear and relaunch app to continue the tests since after relaunch only few screens will be enabled.
To handle this i have added below code in my project

**import 'package:restart_app/restart_app.dart';**

**Restart.restartApp();**

But getting this error

```
DriverError: Failed to fulfill RequestData due to remote error
Original error: ext.flutter.driver: (112) Service has disappeared
Original stack trace:
#0      new _OutstandingRequest (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:1928:45)
#1      VmService._call (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:2493:21)
#2      VmService.callServiceExtension (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:2464:14)
#3      VMServiceFlutterDriver.sendCommand (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/vmservice_driver.dart:322:66)
#4      FlutterDriver.requestData (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/driver.dart:544:45)
#5      integrationDriver (package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart:75:42)
<asynchronous suspension>


#0      VMServiceFlutterDriver.sendCommand (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/vmservice_driver.dart:334:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      FlutterDriver.requestData (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/driver.dart:544:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      integrationDriver (package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart:75:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
```